# SQL Chiper command line

Tags: sqlite

Can anybody advice me what I need to do in order to open ciphered (http://sqlcipher.net/) database in command line.

When I try to do something with it like watch schema it response with following message

```
sqlite> .schema
Error: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

I know password for db, I just want to figure out steps how to correctly open it. My OS is Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I managed to do that, in case if somebody need it, here is my steps:

I've started from http://sqlcipher.net/introduction/ & downloaded sqlcipher.

The first problem was for me that I was unable to configure and build it from source because I have no libcrypto.a which is part of openssl crypto libraries.

I've installed it apt-get install libssl-dev

Then I successfully configured sqlcipher running

```
$./configure --enable-tempstore=yes CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC" LDFLAGS="-lcrypto"
$make
```

after that executable sqlite3 file was created and I was able to open ciphered database.

To provide a password you should execute following statement.

PRAGMA key='password'